# Is my work visa in Germany still valid after being terminated from my job (I'm American)?

Tags: working-visas, germany

I've been in Germany for over 2 years and my Aufenthaltstittel is valid until 2019. I am disputing my termination in court. It has yet to go to trial. I'm wondering though if I am eligible to find another job as well as continue living in Germany.